# Falcon cannot read request body

Tags: python-3.x, rest, gunicorn

I am trying to read a simple request body with JSON data.

The request body:

```
[
{
    ...data
},
{
    ...data
}
]
```

When I try (In `EventResource`)

```
def on_post(self, req, resp):

    print(req.stream.read())
```

The following is logged into the console: `b''`

I have no clue what I am doing wrong or why it is not displaying my body data. Every example I see when doing this it actually logs the data instead of what I am getting.

Requirements.txt (might be some out of context, but I've added the full list just to be sure.)

```
astroid==1.5.3
bson==0.5.0
cffi==1.11.2
click==6.7
falcon==1.4.1
falcon-auth==1.1.0
falcon-jsonify==0.1.1
Flask==0.12.2
greenlet==0.4.12
gunicorn==19.7.1
isort==4.2.15
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
MarkupSafe==1.0
mccabe==0.6.1
mimeparse==0.1.3
mongoengine==0.15.0
pycparser==2.18
PyJWT==1.5.3
pylint==1.7.4
pymongo==3.5.1
python-mimeparse==1.6.0
pytz==2017.3
readline==6.2.4.1
six==1.11.0
Werkzeug==0.12.2
wrapt==1.10.11
```

app.py

```
api = falcon.API(middleware=[
falcon_jsonify.Middleware(help_messages=settings.DEBUG)
])
```

routes.py

```
from app import api
from resources.event import EventResource
from resources.venue import VenueResource

# EventResources
api.add_route('/api/event', EventResource())
api.add_route('/api/event/{event_id}', EventResource())
api.add_route('/api/venue/{venue_id}/events', EventResource())

# VenueResources
api.add_route('/api/venue', VenueResource())
api.add_route('/api/venue/{venue_id}', VenueResource())
api.add_route('/api/event/{event_id}/venue', VenueResource())
```

I run my project with `gunicorn routes:api --reload`

Example POST request (that logs the `b''`):

```
curl -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8000/api/event
```

The only thing I added as a header is `Content-Type`/`application/json`

I've read through [this](https://github.com/falconry/falcon/issues/471) but it didn't help me.

Comment: The simplest example I could put together works perfectly well. Please include a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code you've posted isn't enough for us to help.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks Sorry for the late reply, I've updated my question to hopefully give a better view of what I'm using/trying to do.

Comment: No problem! This may be helpful. Please include how you're making your request as well. I'll try to look again later today.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks Thanks! I've updated my question, also added my requirements.txt that lists all the packages I'm using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior happens because your

```
falcon_jsonify.Middleware(help_messages=settings.DEBUG)
```

The stream is already read by it. You need to use `req.json` in that case. If you remove the middleware then `req.stream.read()` will return the value correctly. If you look at the middleware's `process_request` method

```
def process_request(self, req, resp):
    if not req.content_length:
        return

    body = req.stream.read()
    req.json = {}
    self.req = req
    req.get_json = self.get_json

    try:
        req.json = json.loads(body.decode('utf-8'))

    except ValueError:
        self.bad_request("Malformed JSON", "Syntax error")

    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        self.bad_request("Invalid encoding", "Could not decode as UTF-8")
```

You can see the that middleware reads the body and then spits out the same in `req.json` as a parsed object. But the original body is not saved anywhere else. Once a request stream is read, you have emptied its buffer and won't get the data again. Hence you get `b''`